# Determine the USB port to which my Mobile is connected?

Tags: linux, usb

I tried the following commands, but couldn't find the name of USB port

```
$ lsusb
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04e8:6818 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ cat /etc/fstab
proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=8e93f00d-0154-495b-9c82-d9c485681cda / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=14fe526f-2b5c-429f-87dd-8ab40f4b5093 none swap sw 0 0

$ dmesg | grep tty
[ 0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[ 1.900695] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[ 2.257708] 00:06: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
```

None of the above commands gave the name of the USB port, I want the output as `/dev/sdax` or `ttysax` or something like that.

Any other commands and suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/usb*
```

That should give you a listing of usb devices listed, including your phone.  For me that string looks like:

`usb-Manufacturer_Product_SerialNumber-0:0`

You should see something similar allowing you to easily identify your device.

`ls -l` will show that the device listing is merely a symlink to the actual device node (something like `../../sdc`).  Alternatively, `readlink -e` will give you slightly more straightforward output.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a little clunky, but I'm not knowledgable enough to make the other suggestions work.  If you are in the same boat, try making two files that each contain a list of everything visible in /dev, before and after plugging in the device and then compare them.  From the home directory:

```
touch before after
chmod 777 before after
cd /dev
ls > ~/before
```

Plug in or unplug the device, then:

```
ls > ~/after
cd ~/
diff before after
rm before after
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at

```
fdisk -l
```

before and after pluging in your phone.

OR watch

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

and plug in the phone.

Either way you should be able to deduce the device.

Comment: You could also use dmesg (which is similar to the second option).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any phone to connect, but I guess you should query /sys/ filesystem.